Flutter: The best way to store data, make it accessible for different widgets and calculate it once, on app initialization
I want to store data in similar fashion:
Map countries {
    'abw' : {
      'continent' : "noam",
      'population' : 112269,
      'size' : 180,
      'hasCapital': true
    },
    'afg' : {
      'continent' : "apac",
      'population' : 32890171,
      'size' : 652864,
      'hasCapital': true
    },
    'ago' : {
      'continent' : "afri",
      'population' : 24383301,
      'size' : 1246700,
      'hasCapital': true
    },
    'aia' : {
      'continent' : "noam",
      'population' : 14869,
      'size' : 91,
      'hasCapital': true
    },
    'ala' : {
      'continent' : "euro",
      'population' : 30055,
      'size' : 1580,
      'hasCapital': true
    },
  };

I prefer this way, as it is easy to maintain a large number of records and parameters.
I want to have it accessible from different widgets/pages and I can achieve that with import 'filewithcountries'.
However, I want to create Lists, which would have data filtered, sorted, for example:
Map countriesByContinent = {
    'afri' : ['ago'],
    'apac' : ['afg'],
    'euro' : ['ala'],
    'noam' : ['abw','aia'],
};

List<String> countriesBySize = ['aia', 'abw', 'ala', 'afg', 'ago'];

I know, that I can create helpers which would return such data like this:
List<String> countriesBySize = countries.bySize();

Map countriesByContinent = {
    'afri' : countries.byContinent('afri'),
    'apac' : countries.byContinent('apac'),
    'euro' : countries.byContinent('euro'),
    'noam' : countries.byContinent('noam'),
};

But with such approach I would need to filter/sort that data in every place I need them. I would like to do it once, when application is opened and later just access that data?
How can it be done? I am not interested in created SQL database as it will be more difficult for me to update, manage data.

You can define a Countries class like this:
class Countries {
  static final Map<String, dynamic> countries = {
    'abw': {
      'continent': "noam",
      'population': 112269,
      'size': 180,
      'hasCapital': true
    },
    'afg': {
      'continent': "apac",
      'population': 32890171,
      'size': 652864,
      'hasCapital': true
    },
    'ago': {
      'continent': "afri",
      'population': 24383301,
      'size': 1246700,
      'hasCapital': true
    },
    'aia': {
      'continent': "noam",
      'population': 14869,
      'size': 91,
      'hasCapital': true
    },
    'ala': {
      'continent': "euro",
      'population': 30055,
      'size': 1580,
      'hasCapital': true
    },
  };

  static final List<String> countriesBySize = Map.fromEntries(
          countries.entries.toList()
            ..sort((e1, e2) => e1.value['size'].compareTo(e2.value['size'])))
      .entries
      .map((e) => e.key)
      .toList();

  static final List<String> countriesByPopulation = Map.fromEntries(
          countries.entries.toList()
            ..sort((e1, e2) =>
                e1.value['population'].compareTo(e2.value['population'])))
      .entries
      .map((e) => e.key)
      .toList();
}

Settings Variables as final means you can only set the variable once ensuring its value won't change.
you can use it in your app like this:
 print(Countries.countriesBySize);
 print(Countries.countriesByPopulation);

This approach would only work if countries is constant. If you are willing to update the countries map while the app is running you have to recalculate the sorted variables.

That works like a charm. I was able to make additional function to create a Map of Countries aligned by continents, so my problem is fully solved. Thank you.
